# Can I save a screenshot at a higher resolution than my display is capable of?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My display driver isn't capable of supporting a resolution higher than 1600x900, which means I can't set World of Warcraft to display a higher resolution than this. That being said, is there a way for me to configure the game to save my screenshots at a higher resolution than this?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but you might be able to

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27946/is-it-possible-to-take-high-quality-screen-captures

Comment: Perhaps [Nvidia Ansel](http://www.geforce.com/whats-new/articles/ansel-revolutionizing-game-screenshots) will allow you to do just that?

Comment: @Nolonar it looks like Ansel requires explicit support from the game so likely will not work for WoW. On that note however there is a wow add-on that machinimists use that give the 'freecam' type of functionality, I can't think of the name unfortunately and I don't recall if it had the upscaling feature

Comment: For reference the tool is [Free Far Sight](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1425615-Free-Far-Sight-the-new-Wow-Machinima-Tool)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the quality of screenshots from within the game.

```
/console screenshotQuality 10
```